# Translate custom MKT projection to proj4 string?

Tags: coordinate-system, srid

I need to use [a specific custom projection](https://spatialreference.org/ref/sr-org/albers-conical-equal-area-brazil-sirgas-2000/) that not exist as SRID into standard `spatial_ref_sys` of my GIS,

```
PROJCS["Conica_Equivalente_de_Albers_Brasil",
    GEOGCS["GCS_SIRGAS2000",
        DATUM["D_SIRGAS2000",
            SPHEROID["Geodetic_Reference_System_of_1980",6378137,298.2572221009113]],
        PRIMEM["Greenwich",0],
        UNIT["Degree",0.017453292519943295]],
    PROJECTION["Albers"],
    PARAMETER["standard_parallel_1",-2],
    PARAMETER["standard_parallel_2",-22],
    PARAMETER["latitude_of_origin",-12],
    PARAMETER["central_meridian",-54],
    PARAMETER["false_easting",5000000],
    PARAMETER["false_northing",10000000],
    UNIT["Meter",1]]
```

so I created new arbitrary SRID for it,

```
INSERT into spatial_ref_sys (srid, auth_name, auth_srid, proj4text, srtext)
values ( 952019, 'BR:IBGE', 52019, '', 'PROJCS["Conica_Equivalente_de_Albers_Brasil",      GEOGCS["GCS_SIRGAS2000",          DATUM["D_SIRGAS2000",              SPHEROID["Geodetic_Reference_System_of_1980",6378137,298.2572221009113]],          PRIMEM["Greenwich",0],          UNIT["Degree",0.017453292519943295]],      PROJECTION["Albers"],      PARAMETER["standard_parallel_1",-2],      PARAMETER["standard_parallel_2",-22],      PARAMETER["latitude_of_origin",-12],      PARAMETER["central_meridian",-54],      PARAMETER["false_easting",5000000],      PARAMETER["false_northing",10000000],      UNIT["Meter",1]]');
```

but `ST_Transform(ST_SetSRID(geom,4674),952019)`  is an error:

```
 ERROR:  AddToPROJ4SRSCache: could not parse proj4 string ''
```

So, seems I need to insert also the proj4text column... I **need to parse  the MKT definition** of `srtext`, is it?  How to do it?

---

PS: I am using PostGIS 2 but the question seems generic, about simple parsing procedure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find the Proj.4 string with gdalsrsinfo utility. You may need GDAL version 3.x. I used GDAL 3.1.0dev

```
gdalsrsinfo "PROJCS["Conica_Equivalente_de_Albers_Brasil",    GEOGCS["GCS_SIRGAS2000",        DATUM["D_SIRGAS2000",            SPHEROID["Geodetic_Reference_System_of_1980",6378137,298.2572221009113]],        PRIMEM["Greenwich",0],        UNIT["Degree",0.017453292519943295]],    PROJECTION["Albers"],    PARAMETER["standard_parallel_1",-2],    PARAMETER["standard_parallel_2",-22],    PARAMETER["latitude_of_origin",-12],    PARAMETER["central_meridian",-54],    PARAMETER["false_easting",5000000],    PARAMETER["false_northing",10000000],    UNIT["Meter",1]]"

PROJ.4 : +proj=aea +lat_0=-12 +lon_0=-54 +lat_1=-2 +lat_2=-22 +x_0=5000000 +y_0=10000000 +ellps=GRS80 +units=m +no_defs

OGC WKT2:2018 :
PROJCRS["Conica_Equivalente_de_Albers_Brasil",
    BASEGEOGCRS["GCS_SIRGAS2000",
        DATUM["D_SIRGAS2000",
            ELLIPSOID["Geodetic_Reference_System_of_1980",6378137,298.257222100911,
                LENGTHUNIT["metre",1,
                    ID["EPSG",9001]]]],
        PRIMEM["Greenwich",0,
            ANGLEUNIT["Degree",0.0174532925199433]]],
    CONVERSION["unnamed",
        METHOD["Albers Equal Area",
            ID["EPSG",9822]],
        PARAMETER["Latitude of false origin",-12,
            ANGLEUNIT["Degree",0.0174532925199433],
            ID["EPSG",8821]],
        PARAMETER["Longitude of false origin",-54,
            ANGLEUNIT["Degree",0.0174532925199433],
            ID["EPSG",8822]],
        PARAMETER["Latitude of 1st standard parallel",-2,
            ANGLEUNIT["Degree",0.0174532925199433],
            ID["EPSG",8823]],
        PARAMETER["Latitude of 2nd standard parallel",-22,
            ANGLEUNIT["Degree",0.0174532925199433],
            ID["EPSG",8824]],
        PARAMETER["Easting at false origin",5000000,
            LENGTHUNIT["metre",1],
            ID["EPSG",8826]],
        PARAMETER["Northing at false origin",10000000,
            LENGTHUNIT["metre",1],
            ID["EPSG",8827]]],
    CS[Cartesian,2],
        AXIS["(E)",east,
            ORDER[1],
            LENGTHUNIT["metre",1,
                ID["EPSG",9001]]],
        AXIS["(N)",north,
            ORDER[2],
            LENGTHUNIT["metre",1,
                ID["EPSG",9001]]]]
```

Try to insert this into PostGIS:

```
+proj=aea +lat_0=-12 +lon_0=-54 +lat_1=-2 +lat_2=-22 +x_0=5000000 +y_0=10000000 +ellps=GRS80 +units=m +no_defs
```

Comment: Hi, seems perfect (!), I will test today. About `ellps=GRS80`, can I replace to `ellps=WGS84`? it is [considered identical to WGS84](https://wiki.osgeo.org/wiki/Brazilian_Coordinate_Reference_Systems#SIRGAS_2000).    About MKT's `ANGLEUNIT` information, it is ok to lose it in Proj4?